# SIMD Vectorisation of pointer dereference into bool array, AND/NAND results

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, simd

I am trying to optimise the following simple algorithm, targeting SIMD instructions in both x86-64 as well as arm64. Given a vector `T` of bits, and two vectors `Aidx` and `Bidx` of the same size as `T`, containing indexes to values in `T`, a function would generate a new `T'` using the following algorithm:

```
A = T[Aidx]
B = T[Bidx]
T' = A NAND B
```

---

Here's a C++ implementation:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

#define align 128
#define vsize 1024

struct alignas(align) vec_friendly_idx {
    const static std::size_t size = vsize;
    unsigned short v[size];
};

struct alignas(align) vec_friendly_bool {
    const static std::size_t size = vsize;
    unsigned char v[size];
};

void vecadd3(vec_friendly_bool& __restrict t, const vec_friendly_idx& aidx, const vec_friendly_idx& bidx, vec_friendly_bool& __restrict a, vec_friendly_bool& __restrict b) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != vec_friendly_idx::size; i++) {
        a.v[i] = t.v[aidx.v[i]];
        b.v[i] = t.v[bidx.v[i]];
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != vec_friendly_idx::size; i++) {
        t.v[i] = !(a.v[i] & b.v[i]);
    }
}
```

GCC generates the following arm64 code:

```
        mov     x5, 0
.L2:
        ldrh    w7, [x1, x5, lsl 1]
        ldrh    w6, [x2, x5, lsl 1]
        ldrb    w7, [x0, w7, sxtw]
        ldrb    w6, [x0, w6, sxtw]
        strb    w7, [x3, x5]
        strb    w6, [x4, x5]
        add     x5, x5, 1
        cmp     x5, 1024
        bne     .L2
        movi    v2.16b, 0x1
        mov     x1, 0
.L3:
        ldr     q0, [x4, x1]
        ldr     q1, [x3, x1]
        and     v0.16b, v0.16b, v1.16b
        cmeq    v0.16b, v0.16b, #0
        and     v0.16b, v2.16b, v0.16b
        str     q0, [x0, x1]
        add     x1, x1, 16
        cmp     x1, 1024
        bne     .L3
        ret
```

---

Main question for acceptance:

**Q1.** Any ideas on how to further optimise this?

Bonus questions for comprehension:

**Q2.** While the NAND calculation is clearly vectorised (thus performing just 64 iterations), the vector indexation is not (performing 1024 iters). I was under the impression that [gather-collect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gather/scatter_(vector_addressing)) instructions would be helpful here; but maybe I am wrong?

**Q3.** I also thought about packing the bits in `T` would allow an even quicker NAND (right now, 7 bits are junk), but I have the feeling that the necessary packing/unpacking overhead would not result in a faster execution?

Comment: Do you need to produce the `a[]` and `b[]` bool array outputs for later use, or can those temporaries be optimized down to just copying a new `t[]` into place.  Or better, a level of indirection for `t` so you could index the old `t` while storing into the new `t` without having to copy at the end.  Overlapping the bitwise AND work with the non-contiguous loads is probably better than doing 2x 2-byte stores instead of 1x 1-byte store and having to do it separately.

Comment: I have no idea how you intend to optimise that, but `a[]` and `b[]` are indeed just temporaries. Modifying `t` in-place would lead to `aidx` and `bidx` to potentially point to newer values of `t` before the full iteration ends, which is undesirable. But because `aidx` and `bidx` are constants, one could translate them (once) to memory pointers instead of indexes (if it helps?).

Comment: x86 gathers are only available with 32 and 64-bit element size, like `vpgatherdd` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherdd:vpgatherqd).  For bool elements, you could gather unaligned 4-byte chunks and pack down to boolean.  For AArch64, I think gathers are only available with SVE, which very few CPUs have yet. (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101726/4-0/Learn-about-the-Scalable-Vector-Extension--SVE-/What-is-the-Scalable-Vector-Extension-)  Bit-packing to 8 bits per byte makes indexing more expensive, unless you have a bit-shuffle for your 1024 bits or something.

Comment: Yes, I realize you can't just modify `t` in place, that's why I suggested a level of indirection where you'd write into a new `t`, then change the pointer when you're done.  Like two global `vec_friendly_bool`s, and a pointer that can be to either.  (Or just `new` / `delete` if allocation overhead isn't a problem, a smallish array like 1KiB should stay on a free list and get reallocated without a system call.)

Comment: `aidx` and `bidx` are constants, like compile-time constants?  Perhaps they could get preprocessed into bit-shuffles using `gf2p8affineqb` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/gf2p8affineqb (and `vpermb` or `vpshufb` to move whole bytes around), letting you line up the right bits in SIMD vectors instead of gathering them one at a time.  Or with unpacked bools like you're using now, into a sequence of load and shuffle instructions like AVX512VBMI `vpermt2b` (Ice Lake) to grab 64 bytes from a 128-byte pair of ZMM registers.  1024 bytes is "only" 16 ZMM registers, half of what AVX-512 has.

Comment: Ahhh, that limitation of `vpgatherdd` explains why I wasn't able to convince Julia's SIMD optimiser to use it  -.-' Not sure how your strategy to pack bool elements into unaligned 4-byte chunks would work, but would be keen to see it :D

Comment: No, not `compile-time` constants, sorry. They define the initial state and this function is expected to run hundreds of millions of iterations before it stops. Writing a new `t` and changing the pointer is perfectly doable though, thx for the suggestion :) The size of 1024 is a toy example. In my real-world application, this would probably be much larger.

Comment: That's not what I said.  I mean `_mm256_gather_epi32(t, vec_idx, 1)` so you have 1 bool per 4-byte vector element, at the bottom. Using a scale factor of `1` uses your indexes as byte offsets, so unaligned-dword loads.  That means you'd have to unpack the halfworld indices to 32-bit, and pack the results back down to 1 bool per byte, e.g. with 2x `vpackssdw` + `vpacksswb` after bitwise stuff that leaves each 4-byte element being 0 or 1.  i.e. emulate a byte gather using a dword gather, as long as reading up to 3 bytes past the end of `t[]` won't fault or be super slow.

Comment: You don't get any gather instructions in your assembly because, as Peter said, base ARMv8 SIMD hasn't got any.  SVE does, and if you compile for SVE then gcc will use them: https://godbolt.org/z/4vGxE79q1, see the `ld1*` instructions with a `z` register in the effective address, like `ld1b z0.s, p0/z, [x0, z0.s, sxtw]`.

Comment: Minor improvement: Use `~(a.v[i] & b.v[i])` to replace the byte-comparison by an XOR operation (you should store true values as `0xff` in that case). Bit-packing `T` is probably worth it, if you could fit all elements into one ore two vectors (maybe 4 vectors) and do the lookup using shuffling inside a register and some bit-shifting.

Comment: @chtz: Good idea to use vector shifts like AVX2 `vpsrlvd` to deal with the bit-within-element portion of the index for packed booleans.  Either after shuffles or gather loads.  (And if you're splitting each index into chunk and bit-within-chunk, your gather elements can be 32-bit aligned).  So yeah, even 8 bools per vector is useful.  I was giving up after not seeing a way to do 128 or 256 bits per vector, but there is middle ground between  scalar and a full bit-shuffle.

Comment: I think there's a lot of good information here that would merit acceptable replies to the "any ideas on how to further optimise this?". Does any of you would like to further expand on your comments and provide a formal answer?